# What is the syntax of array literal in H2 db?

Tags: sql, h2

I need to write an insert query where one value is an array of 3 elements.
I've tried to do it like this:

```
  INSERT INTO some_table (id, col) VALUES (1, '{1, 2, 3}');
```

The sintax I've used for 'col' value is valid array literal in PostrgreSQL but H2 treats it as a single value of the array but not as an array with 3 elements.

Table DDL:

```
  CREATE TABLE some_table (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY ,
    col ARRAY
  );
```

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO some_table (id, col) VALUES (1, (1, 2, 3))`

Comment: @lad2025. Yes. It works. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [SQL Grammar](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#array):

[image]

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, col) VALUES (1, (1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

For SQL that will work in both H2 and PostrgreSQL, you can use `ARRAY [1, 2, 3]`. So the full query would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (id, col) VALUES (1, ARRAY [1, 2, 3]);
```